# No Limits on Text in Limited Space With No Wrapping

Tags: php, html, css

This is a problem I seem to run into over and over with clients. They have a limited amount of space for a title, say like an image caption. The space is limited because it's in a series of boxes floating next to each other, let's say. However, the client baulks at an attempt to put a cap on the title length. Yet at the same time, they don't want this text to wrap.

I've tried several different methods to tackle problems like this over time...something similar to `text-overflow`, when `strlen()` is used to add ellipsis to the overflowing text, with the `full text` in a title attribute, I've tried re-sizing fonts based on `strlen()` to make text fit.

Just wondering if anyone had a more elegant solution for situations like this?

Comment: Not really a PHP problem

Comment: Seems like more of a discussion topic, but this may help you: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: Use marquee <ducks and runs>

Comment: Yes, I was hesitant to post the question, but I didn't see anything else quite like it, so I figured it was worth a shot. I marked it as PHP because that's what I'm working with, and in case there were any functions that could help, like ps_hyphenate, for example.

Comment: "Caption" - : a title or **brief** explanation accompanying an illustration. What part of 'brief' don't they understand?

Comment: I know...sometimes I overlook obvious and/or simple solutions, so I posted in case I was missing something. Rereading this, it seems like a silly question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but if you're saying a valid solution is the ellipsis then that can be accomplished in CSS using the following stylings

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

No need to use Php.

Comment: I like this one for avoiding yet another plugin. Sorry, it was a dumb question to begin with, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively from the CSS solution you could also look into this jQuery solution if the client doesn't mind the ellipsis.

http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

The benefit with this is your full text is still on the page for indexing and ranking purposes.